# Alignment of Lightning button and input Text in a single line

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I need to remove the alignment issue from my below code of lightning component ,i dont know where I am going wrong. I want to align the input text field and Brand button in the same line.

Component :-

```
     <lightning:layout verticalAlign="center" horizontalAlign="spread" pullToBoundary="small">
     <lightning:layoutItem  flexibility="auto" padding="horizontal-small">

     <lightning:input name="input1" placeholder="Enter some text" />
                </lightning:layoutItem>
     <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="auto" padding="horizontal-small">

     <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Brand" title="Brand action" />
                </lightning:layoutItem>
     </lightning:layout>
```

My output is as shown in the Image[image: Brand Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `variant="label-hidden"` to remove the excess space above the input:

```
<lightning:input name="input1" placeholder="Enter some text" variant="label-hidden"/>
```

Comment: ...thats so nice of you...Once again u came to my rescue,will be very grateful to you. Thnx.